# Cancel control postback

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to cancel OnTextChanged postback when it meets certain condition at code behind without using javascript??

Answer (score 1):

you just contradicted yourself:

> cancel OnTextChanged postback

and

> when it meets certain condition at code behind

you can't get to code behind unless you PostBack

p.s. what's the problem with using javascript? give more details on your scenario, and you might get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to do it client-side, you would have to use [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx) in codebehind on the server side, but by then it's too late; the postback has already occurred.

So you can't cancel the postback, but you *can* redisplay the page.